# Can't connect to mongo with nodeJs on raspberry Pi

Tags: node.js, linux, mongodb, raspberry-pi3

with this code on nodeJS :

```
 var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
...
 MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017', { useUnifiedTopology: true },  (error, db) => {
                if (error) {
                    obs.error(this.throwExceptionError(error));
                } else {
                    this.dbConnect = db.db(dbb);
                    obs.next(true);
                }
            });
```

i can connect to MongoDB on windows and it works well.

I try to execute this code on my raspberry Pi but the code didn't work.
I installed mongodb, launch :

```
service mongodb start
```

When i execute mongo in a console, it works and i see my dbs and my collections.

The log of the mongoDb are :

```
Sun Jun 28 13:43:51.566 [initandlisten]
Sun Jun 28 13:43:51.566 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.14
Sun Jun 28 13:43:51.566 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
Sun Jun 28 13:43:51.566 [initandlisten] build info: Linux bm-wb-03 3.19.0-trunk-armmp #1 SMP Debian 3.19.1-1~exp1+plugwash1 (2015-03-28) armv7l BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_58
Sun Jun 28 13:43:51.566 [initandlisten] allocator: system
Sun Jun 28 13:43:51.566 [initandlisten] options: { bind_ip: "127.0.0.1", config: "/etc/mongodb.conf", dbpath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: "true", logappend: "true", logpath: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log", port: 27017 }
Sun Jun 28 13:43:51.578 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongodb/journal
Sun Jun 28 13:43:51.578 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Sun Jun 28 13:43:51.606 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
Sun Jun 28 13:43:51.606 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

And the command "netstat -tulpn"

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo netstat -tulpn
Connexions Internet actives (seulement serveurs)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Adresse locale          Adresse distante        Etat        PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3407/mongod         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5900            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      486/vncserver-x11-c 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:28017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3407/mongod         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      495/sshd
```

So i think the server is running...

I don't understand why i can't connect to mongoDB on my raspberry pi.

help plz ^^

Comment: Where are you connecting from? Is the server running on the PI and you're connecting from a PC? Or are you running the server and connecting to it all from the PI? Also as a side note, to start the mongo server it's `sudo service mongod start`, not `mongodb`.

Comment: The service mongod don't exist. it's not in the list when i launch systemctl list-unit-files --type=service. The node server is on my raspberry too, same server

Comment: Then it's not installed. You must not have done it properly so you need to revisit that. I'm not an expert on Raspberry PI but I know for a fact that the mongodb server process is called `mongod`. Also are you trying to connect to the PI from another PC on your local network? If so then you need to change the mongodb config `bind-ip` setting to the PI's local network address, not localhost. 127.0.0.1 is for connecting to the current device only. To connect to a different device from another you need to use the local network address for that device.

Comment: Following this link https://pimylifeup.com/mongodb-raspberry-pi/ ,on a raspberry pi it's mongodb. I have an anguler server on another PC which connect on the nodeJs server on the raspberry PI. The nodeJs server try to connect to the mongo server which is on the same raspberry pi (localhost).

Comment: Ah okay, that's good info to have. I see they are actually using `mongod` in that tutorial to start the daemon process using `systemctl`, that's how you make it run as a background process if you need it to run forever and allow you to do other things. I do see that there are two `mongod` processes in your `netstat`. Is that intentional? Did you try connecting to the one on port `28017`?

Comment: Sorry, i was out for a loooong time. I try connecting on the port 18017 but it don't workk...